# How to merge 4 functions in one function?

Tags: javascript

I’m setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application.How to merge 4 functions in one function?

Java Script

```
createaccount = () => {
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('register').style.display = "block"
}


forgotpassword = () => {
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('forgot').style.display = "block"
}


back = () => {
  document.getElementById('register').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block"
}


backlogin = () => {
  document.getElementById('forgot').style.display = "none"
  document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block"
}
```

Comment: simply just put all code stuff in one fuction.

Comment: Just make a function that takes in two strings and changes one element to `display: none` and the other to `display: block`.

Comment: How is this related to UTF-8? How exactly are these functions used? Do you want to create a fifth function that these four functions would call?

Comment: Stardust's comment seems to be the right idea. But what does any of this have to do with UTF-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a function with 2 parameters for the `id` like this:

```js
function my_function(id_1, id_2) {
    document.getElementById(id_1).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(id_2).style.display = "block";
}
```

Then call the function this way:

```js
my_function('login', 'register');
my_function('forgot', 'register');
my_function('register', 'login');
my_function('forgot', 'login');
```

Comment: This loses the semantic names (e.g. `createAccount`, `forgotPassword`, etc.).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Not quite. You can (and should) do `createaccount = () => my_function('login', 'register');` in order to keep the nice naming.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use conditions :

```js
const accountOperations = (operation) => {
  if(operation === 'createAccount'){
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('register').style.display = "block"
  } else if (operation === 'forgotpassword') {
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('forgot').style.display = "block"
  } else if (operation === 'back') {
    document.getElementById('register').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block"
  } else if (operation === 'backlogin'){
    document.getElementById('forgot').style.display = "none"
    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block"
  }
}
// then for example 
// accountOperations('createAccount')
```

Comment: This is more verbose than it needs to be. Simply use some object whose keys are the operations and whose values are the IDs.

Comment: @Bobyy `<button onclick="accountOperations('createAccount')">Create</button>` and same for the other buttons you just change the parameter to the operation you want

Answer (score 0):

Simple forEach does it

```js
const showBlock = (elToShowSelector) => {
  const elmToShow = document.querySelector(elToShowSelector);

  document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-group')
    .forEach(el => el.style.display = (el !== elmToShow) ? 'none' : 'block');
};

// Example 1
showBlock('#login');
// Example 2
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons[0].onclick = showBlock.bind(this, '#login');
buttons[1].onclick = showBlock.bind(this, '#register');
buttons[2].onclick = showBlock.bind(this, '#forgot');
```

```css
.toggle-group {
  display: none;
  padding: 10;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<button>Login</button><button>Register</button><button>Forgot</button>
<div id="login" class="toggle-group">Login</div>
<div id="register" class="toggle-group">Register</div>
<div id="forgot" class="toggle-group">Forgot</div>
```